# How to set background image for a View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, view

the default background color is white and I want to change it to an image

I have tried this:

```
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

but the background turn black, the image is not at the background. I don't know why.

by the way if I have more than 1 image in one view, how to set their priority of display?

Comment: that should work, are you sure you imported your image?

Comment: it works now ,but i really dont know why...i changed nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imageone"]];
backgroundView.frame = self.view.bounds;
[[self view] addSubview:backgroundView];
```

Try this out, this is calling `self.view.bounds` for the frame instead of `self.view.frame` for frame. I just tested it and it works perfectly.

EDIT: If all you're looking for is to send the image to the back of the stack, you can do the following and select send to back.

[image]

Comment: this works for me. Make sure you have the image actually imported correctly.

Comment: I have never seen the image on the view with these kinds of method... sometimes it's white, sometimes is black... maybe there is some problems somewhere else. Only when I put a "Image View" on my .xib file, the image shows up, but it's on the front not the back...

Comment: I see you are new to this website, so please choose the answer here that you believed helped you the most, and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Code for you :

```
    UIImageView *myImage = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]autorelease];
myImage.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:myImage];
```

Comment: i have forget [self.view addSubview:myImage]; try with ;)

Comment: u r so kind, but the background stay white...T.T

Answer (score 0):

You should to use a UIImageView and its frame is uiview's frame.